# Морфемный состав слова

Tags: морфология

Проверьте, пожалуйста.

***Корковый***
Корень - КОР; суффикс - К; суффикс - ОВ; окончание - ЫЙ. 
Основа слова: КОРКОВ.

***Ослепительный*** 
Приставка - О; корень - СЛЕП; суффикс - И; суффикс - ТЕЛЬН; окончание - ЫЙ. 
Основа слова: ОСЛЕПИТЕЛЬН.

***Невесело*** 
Приставка - НЕ; корень - ВЕСЕЛ; окончание - О. 
Основа слова: НЕВЕСЕЛ.

***Переделывать***
Приставка - ПЕРЕ, корень - дел, суффикс - ев, окончание - ать.  
Основа - переделыв.

***Знающий***
Корень - ЗНА; суффикс - ЮЩ; окончание - ИЙ. 
Основа слова: ЗНАЮЩ.

***Атомоходный***
Корень - атом, суффикс - о, корень - ход, суффикс н, окончание - ый.
Основа слова - атомоходн.

***Беспробудный***
приставка - БЕС; приставка - ПРО; корень - БУД; суффикс - Н; окончание - ЫЙ. 
Основа слова: БЕСПРОБУДН.

***Мешковатый***
Корень - МЕШК; суффикс - ОВАТ; окончание - ЫЙ. 
Основа слова: МЕШКОВАТ.

***Молодёжный***
Корень - молод, суффикс- ЁЖ, суффикс- Н, окончание - ый.

***Вмешательство***
Приставка - В; корень - МЕШ; суффикс - А; суффикс - ТЕЛЬ; суффикс - СТВ; окончание - О. 
Основа слова: ВМЕШАТЕЛЬСТВ

***Излечимый***
Приставка - ИЗ; корень - ЛЕЧ; суффикс - ИМ; окончание - ЫЙ. 
Основа слова: ИЗЛЕЧИМ.

***Картофелекопалка***
Корень - КАРТОФЕЛ; соединительная гласная - Е; корень - КОП; суффикс - А; суффикс - ЛК; окончание - А. 
Основа слова: КАРТОФЕЛЕКОПАЛК.

***Перерытый***
Приставка - ПЕРЕ; корень - РЫ; суффикс - Т; окончание - ЫЙ. 
Основа слова: ПЕРЕРЫТ.

***Предостерегающий***
Приставка - ПРЕД; корень - ОСТЕРЕГ; суффикс - А; суффикс - ЮЩ; окончание - ИЙ.  
Основа слова: ПРЕДОСТЕРЕГАЮЩ.

***Лебединый***
Корень - ЛЕБЕД; суффикс - ИН; окончание - ЫЙ. 
Основа слова: ЛЕБЕДИН.

***Выводок***
Приставка - ВЫ; корень - ВОД; суффикс - ОК; нулевое окончание. 
Основа слова: ВЫВОДОК.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корковый
Корень - КОРК; суффикс - ОВ; окончание - ЫЙ. 
Основа слова: КОРКОВ. Нельзя сказать, что корка - это маленькая кора. Кора и корка - разные значения.

Невесело
Приставка - НЕ; корень - ВЕСЕЛ; суфф. - О. 
Основа слова: НЕВЕСЕЛО (наречие, неизменяемое, оконч. нет).

Переделывать
Приставка - ПЕРЕ, корень - дел, суффикс -ыва, суфф./окончание - ть (в зависимости от того, как трактуется в Вашей школе. Если это вуз - только суффикс).
Основа - переделыва.

Атомоходный
Корень - атом, интерфикс (соединит. гласный, его нельзя назвать суффиксом) - о, корень - ход, суффикс н, окончание - ый.
Основа слова - атомоходн.

Предостерегающий
Приставка - ПРЕД; прист. О; корень - СТЕРЕГ; суффикс - А; суффикс - ЮЩ; окончание - ИЙ. 
Основа слова: ПРЕДОСТЕРЕГАЮЩ.

Comment: "Кора и корка - разные значения..."  См.:

КОРА… 2.Твёрдый, отвердевший слой чего-л.; корка.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EA%EE%F0%E0
+
КОРКА 1.=Кора (2 зн.)... 
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EA%EE%F0%EA%E0

Comment: Да, в одном из значений они совпадают(наружный уплотнённый слой), но мы говорим о словообразовании прилаг.-го.Кора- древесная, ледяная, земная.От этого сущ. нет современного прилагательного. Исторически корка от коры, но сейчас нельзя сказать"корка-это маленькая кора"(как норка-это маленькая нора.Корка-апельсиновая,хлебная.От него уменьшит.корочка.От"корка" прил.корковый возможно.Корковый слой - наружный слой, уплотнённый. А вообще-то это термин.Ко́рковое де́рево -"пробковый дуб", через польск. korek от исп. соrсhо или мед.-наружная часть органа-корковый анализатор,корковое вещество почки.

Comment: Словаристы с Вами не согласны. У Ефремовой и Кузнецовой (Словарь морфем русского языка) -- корень "кор". У Тихонова (во всех мне известных словарях) -- "кор"; и производит он "корку" именно от "коры". И разбор его слова "корковый" соответствует тому, что есть  у elenaalisa. 

См.: https://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9/

Comment: Однажды я подвела студентку, согласившись с её разбором под/кор/к/ов/ый уровень. Ей исправили: корень - корк-, я подумала и решила, что это действительно верно, это термин, у него есть латинское название. Что от чего произошло - я не знаю, может, подкорка гол. мозга и не от коры,может, это -К- уже было в какой-то форме, просто в русском совпало.

Answer (score 0):

Слово ***невесело*** в разных контекстах может относиться к разным частям речи.

Примеры:

1) *Лицо её было **невесело**.*

2) *Был в меланхолии Подосинников. **Невесело** глядел и доктор Моравский.*

3) *Сегодня я в мерлехлюндии, **невесело** мне.*

В первом примере ***невесело*** -- краткая форма от прилагательного *невесёлый*: ед. ч., ср. р.; окончание ***"а".***

Во втором примере -- наречие, в третьем -- слово категории состояния. Эти части речи -- неизменяемые, окончания не имеют. В них ***"о"*** -- суффикс.

**P.S.**
Для проверки морфемного разбора остальных слов можете воспользоваться Морфемно-орфографическим словарём Тихонова: https://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/